# Escape variables HTML inside a function in JS

Tags: javascript, html, tags, escaping

I need to escape variables for html inside a function in JS, I have something like this:

```
function (foo1) {
   var cat = '<li id="'+ foo1.*** +'"></li>'
           + '<div aria-label="' + foo1.*** + '" tabindex = "0">'
           + '<button id="'+ foo1.*** +'"></button>'
           + '</div>'
}
```

Can this escape be accomplished somehow?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "escape variables for html" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve this problem more elegantly you could use a template engine such as provided by underscore.js (from the docs):

```
var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
compiled({name: 'moe'});
=> "hello: moe"
```

Or https://www.npmjs.com/package/jinja.js/. If you use a framework this functionality might be already built in.